# How do EJS tags and brackets work?

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, ejs

I have a problem with EJS and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

I have a basic `for` loop :

```
    <% for(var i=0; i<users.lenght; i++) { %>
         <li> <%=  users[i]  %> </li>
    <% } %>
```

My problem is that when I insert the last bracket, it looks like the first bracket doesn't see when I close it in the last EJS tags. Here is a  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfXiG.png)

I use the latest Sublime Text 3 UNREGISTRED (I just started to work with Sublime Text a few days ago ). Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you corrected the typo in your first line?  (ie. change lenght to length.)

This code seemed to work fine for me on the [ejs playground](https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/) once I made that change:

```
<% var users = ['Steve', 'Janet', 'Jennifer']; %>

 <% for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
         <li> <%=  users[i]  %> </li>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Yes .. and for some reason .. I solved the problem .. I mean I just made a new EJS file , introduce first the for loop , then the EJS tags , then the html ... and now works .. it doesn't make any sense why .. because all the file content was exactly the same but for some reason now works ..

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you don't have the EJS package syntax installed or else not configured for the file extension that you have for the file in question.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EJS%202

Comment: umm in screenshot if u saw i also have an <h1> tag with EJS tags inside and that part works .. i tryed with EJS / EJS 2 packages (together and separately) same thing .. i also tryed with other syntax tags from EJS 2 - <$$>, <??>, <@@> (after i setup them in syntax view for the EJS file ) same problem :(